# Best practice for configuration in multi maven projects

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

given the following spring boot application layout:

```
app
  --api 
  --component 
  --data
  --xyz
libs
  --lib1
  --lib2
```

Each one is a seperate maven project where "app" contains the spring bootstrap class. Other modules are maven dependencies that are used within the application.

Each modules comes with its own profiled property file (application-dev.properies, application-qa.properties...)

What is the best way to consolidate now all property files within the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My proposal for consolidation:

Each module defines own profile, for example:

application-DEV-lib1.properties
application-QA-lib1.properties
application-DEV-lib2.properties
application-QA-lib2.properties

app defines profiles DEV and QA:

> application-DEV.properties

```
spring.profiles.include=DEV-lib1,DEV-lib2
aaa=123
...
```

---

> application-QA.properties

```
spring.profiles.include=QA-lib1,QA-lib2
aaa=456
...
```